# How can I export an Azure SQL database instance with a db user?

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL database that I want to export using

```
az sql db export  ...
```

Now the username and pwd I use is one that I created on the database, NOT the admin user and password as configured in Azure.

I created the user like this:

```
   CREATE USER [testuser] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;

   ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [testuser];
   ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [testuser];
   ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [testuser];
```

But when I try to do the export, I get an error:

> (ImportExportJobError) The ImportExport operation failed due to 'An unexpected error was returned by SQL.

Are there any additional permissions I need to give that user? Or do I need to use the admin user that was created when I first created the server?

Answer (score 1):

> (ImportExportJobError) The ImportExport operation failed due to 'An unexpected error was returned by SQL.

The error you are facing because you are using AD user and not mentioning the authentication type it by default use it as SQL authentication.

**You can specify the authentication using `--auth-type` command and accepted values:  ADPassword, SQL**

e.g

```
az sql db export -s pds1 -n pdb1 -g resourcegroup --admin-password "password" --admin-user "username" --auth-type ADPassword --storage-key accesskey== --storage-key-type StorageAccessKey --storage-uri "https://storage accname.blob.core.windows.net/folder1/myBacpac.bacpac"
```

**Note - login through service principal is not supported.**

Comment: I have tried that and get the same error. ADPassword , its not an active directory user but a user on the database ?

Comment: The needs to be an Active directory user to login with ADPassword authentication as you created by using `from external provider`.